# Illustrator Image trace: want outline of image, getting unrelated shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, image-trace

I'm getting some very strange output from Illustrator's Image Trace feature. I want to turn this:

[image: Original image]

Into a vector shape. Using the Image trace, I haven't been able to get anything even close. The best I have come up with is using the preset "Technical Drawing" with the color turned on:

[image]

Any suggestions? I have thousands of these (different but similar shapes) in several files, in grids.

I'm using Illustrator 2015.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab outputs the images as a "flat" image inside a .eps wrapper.

A workaround is to rasterize the image first and then try and trace it.

Alternatively for web-use you can output as a scaleable vector graphic (.svg)

Once exported, if the .svg is missing any elements you can save and run [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jvoigts/figure-plot-illustration-tools/master/illustrator/clean%20up%20matlab%20svg.aia) on the file to fix any "missing elements".

Sometimes elements appear missing but that is just Matlab creating a convoluted structure because there are incorrect clipping masks on objects. Also, objects are highly grouped with no particular rhyme or reason.

This is a catch-all script that will remove the masks and return layer structure to more normalized levels.

Comment: Unfortunately deselecting Snap Curves to Lines produces an even worse result (i.e. a curved object). Also, the pen tool (or any other "by hand" method) is out of the question in this case. I have thousands of these (different shaped rectangles) to deal with.

Comment: @Evan Updated answer with settings.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there is something strange going on with my image that I am not seeing. Using those exact settings is still giving me a strange result. Like the one pictured in my question, but curvy.

Comment: @Evan is it just a .jpg?

Comment: The image elements were originally embedded in an .eps file exported by Matlab.

Comment: Why are you tracing an eps? They are editable in Illustrator. Try going to Object-> Expand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71361/discussion-between-ovaryraptor-and-evan).